# помогите, выдаёт ошибку 'list' object has no attribute 'min'

Tags: python

```
import numpy
a = int(input('a = '))
print('Input number: ');    M = [[int(input()) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(4)]
trans_M = zip(*M);  print(*M, sep='\n')
print('Min: ',M.min())
print('Max: ',M.max())
```

Comment: Наверное, дело в том, что у списков нет метода `.min()`. Возможно, вы имели ввиду функцию `min()`.

Comment: Если вопрос для вас закрыт, отметьте ответ @Mango как решение.

Answer (score 2):

```
print('Min: ',min(M))
print('Max: ',max(M))
```

первая половина вашего кода у меня не работает, но если ошибка у вас только `'list' object has no attribute 'min'` то ответ должен помочь

Comment: Спасибо, код уже исправил. работает

Answer (score 0):

вот такое получилось решение:

```
import numpy as np
print('Task #1')
s = 0; row = 3; col = 4; a = []
print('Input number: ')
M = [[int(input()) 
for _ in range(row)]
    for _ in range(col)]
trans_M = zip(*M);  print(*M, sep='\n')
for row in M: 
    s += sum(row)

print('1.Min: ',np.min(M))
print('2.Max: ', np.max(M))
print('3.Sum: ', s)                     
print('4.Mid: ', s/12);
```